# How init angularjs's $rootScope in multiply js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry, for my English.
I have angularjs app with many pages and forms.
For any page created file with Models for this page.
Example:

```
file userDict.js:

$rootScope.dicts.user = {
    userTypes : { ... },
    maxAge : ...,
    minAge : ... ,
    ...
}

file companyDict.js:

$rootScope.dicts.company = {
        companyTypes : { ... },
        blabla : ...,
        blabla : ... ,
        ...
    }

files *Dict.js
....
....
```

And in `UserController` I use `$rootScope.dicts.user`, in `CompanyController` - `$rootScope.dicts.company`.

This is done for ease of separation large models.

But how to make that in each js models file calls `$rootScope.dicts.??? = { ... }` ?

How wrapping each file with models, that they calling during init app?

for example, if I wrote it using plane jQuery, I would do it so for each file

```
file userDict.js:

$(document).ready(function(){

   $rootScope.dicts.user = {
    userTypes : { ... },
    maxAge : ...,
    minAge : ... ,
    ...
}
});
```

Comment: You should read more about factories and services. I'd advise against storing data in $rootScope as it might quickly get unmaintainable, services will provide you with same functionality but will separate data in nice namespaced manner

Comment: @maurycy I read about factories and services. But If use them, will have to create separate service for each models file. I think this is excessive.

Comment: by each model you mean a group like 'user'?

Comment: @maurycy I updated question. I have different models. For user Controller I want to use models from one file, for other controlles - from other files.

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understood, what you want, you have two options to do it.

1) In the first option you should do it smth like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.dicts = {}; 
    $rootScope.dicts.user = "rootScope";
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {    
    $scope.userDict = $rootScope.dicts.user;
})
.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {    
    $scope.userDict = $rootScope.dicts.user;
});
```

This is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TmPk5/144/) for this example.

This code provide possibility to getting of `$rootScope` variables from any controller.

But you don't forget to inject `$rootScope` to controller.

2) The second option is using of **shared service**.

```
myApp.factory('sharedService', function () {
    var sharedService = {};
    sharedService.dict = {};
    sharedService.dict.user = "any value";

    return sharedService;
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.user = sharedService.dict.user;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.user = sharedService.dict.user;
});
```

Comment: That's what I meant when said use services, $rootScope isn't good place for storing data

Comment: Thx for your response.  I updated question for a better understanding me. I can't init all models in `angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($rootScope) {` because I have a lot of data. Therefore i create separated files. But i cant call `module('myApp', []).run` in each file, angular does not allow doing it. And my question - how make each models file executable at startup.

Comment: @gooogenot, You shouldn't call module('myApp', []).run in each file. It's enough to initialize your models at once. If you inject $rootScope after initializing, you will contain your values from it in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @artyom-paranovich answer, i think you have 2 options.

The first and better solution is to put your data as a service. Note that Services aren't only for DB data but for general data as you are doing.
I would write an example but @artyom-paranovich did an excellent job for it.
My Advice that you will take this approach.

The second options is to wrap your data in div and to give that div a controller so it would be the parent of all of your sub controller. That way you can initiate your data in the parent controller and all your sub controller could have access to it

Your HTML:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-contoller="ParentController"> 
            <div ng-contoller="subController1"> </div>
            <div ng-contoller="subController2"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ParentController.js

```
myApp.controller('ParentController', function ($scopeScope) {
    $rootScope.dicts.user = {
        userTypes : { ... },
        maxAge : ...,
        minAge : ... ,
        ...
    };
}
});
```

Comment: Now my realization done like u answer. But I want to make separeted file `parentDict.js` with init `$rootScope`, because have many logic in `ParentController.js`.